# Is there a way to set CSS properties like `display` using Cypress commands?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cypress

I would like to hide an element by setting the display property.

I've tried using `invoke` to set the attribute value, but it may only work for HTML attributes?

```
cy.get('#hubspot-messages-iframe-container > iframe')
        .invoke('attr', 'display', 'none!important')
        .should('have.attr', 'display', 'none!important')
```

This seems to be setting the attribute values, but the element is still visible, which leads me to believe it's probably not recognizing my attribute or i'm using the wrong command.

Tried using this as suggested:

[image]

The .css() function seems to not be setting the value the way it should:

[image]

Here's me validating my own sanity that the selector is correct and the display is `none` lol: 
[image]

Comment: You can't use `!important` with it, but it doesn't matter, you don't need `!important` - it has no effect here.

Comment: I tried with just ```none``` but that didn't work, so I tried this way as well

Comment: Can you share the spec code where you tried with `none` and it didn't work? I tested the answer I shared locally, so it ought to work.

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be `.css('display', 'none !important')` instead of `.css(display, none!important)`, referring to the lack of quotation marks.

Comment: @MihailMinkov that's a good guess, I tried this ```"'display'", "'none'"``` and it shows in the output now as ```.css('display', 'none')``` but it's still not updating the value

Comment: @James I just double-checked that the code I posted works with `<iframe>`s, and it does. You cannot use `!important`, and you don't need to do `"'display'", "'none'"`. That exact code I posted is the correct way to do this, and it should work unless something else in your spec is interfering with it. Maybe you forgot to press Ctrl+S when you were testing it out? Happens to the best of us!

Comment: @ZachBloomquist I don't get it, I'm running the same code, I'm saving each time to trigger Cypress to auto re-run the tests

Comment: Can you share the text of your entire specfile? https://pastebin.com/ works

Comment: sorry, left bad code in ```commands.js```, this is the right one : https://pastebin.com/yXRdsQZp

Comment: You didn't share your spec that's actually using the command. Can you share the text of your entire specfile please?

Comment: sorry bout that here's the spec https://pastebin.com/kEEexXEL

Comment: Did you check my recommendation below @James?

Comment: @MihailMinkov I did yes, no go.  What's weird is that the value is ```block``` but I can clearly see the value of the iframe is ```none``` in dev tools.  It feels like maybe I have the wrong selector.  Cypress mirrors some of this stuff and ends up duplicating iframes I think.

Comment: could you use some sort of class or identificator other than the parent container id?

Comment: @James The only thing I'm noticing now is that there's a difference between your command log and mine. Check out what mine looks like: https://i.imgur.com/A9lg9En.png See how I don't have a `WRAP` in my command log? Maybe you're defining `hideHubSpot` twice, or you have extra code in `hideHubSpot` that's doing the `WRAP`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This seems to work folks.  I believe `initial !important` is a reference of some sort and not an actual value and maybe that's why `.css()` wouldn't work.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('hideHubSpot', () => {
    cy.get('#hubspot-messages-iframe-container')
        .invoke('attr', 'style', 'display: none')
        .should('have.attr', 'style', 'display: none')
```

Comment: I did help in some ways haha @James

Comment: jus out of curiosity, why the image instead of the code snippet?

Answer (score 7):

You can invoke the [`css` function from jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/css/) using `invoke` to change the CSS. Note that your `!important` won't work, but you don't need it, since setting CSS via Javascript will override any other styles on the item.

Then you can just use the `have.css` assertion from the [Assertion List](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Chai-jQuery) to check, if you need to.

Here's what that would look like:

```js
cy.get('#hubspot-messages-iframe-container > iframe')
  // use the .css function from jquery, since Cypress yields jquery elements
  .invoke('css', 'display', 'none')
  .should('have.css', 'display', 'none')
```

Comment: it seems this doesn't work because of the way .css() works - I believe it's a rule on the style sheet that's disallowing jquery to set the value that's inherited from the ```<body>```

Answer (score 3):

If it's CSS you're after, you should probably use style instead of attribute.

I am not sure how cypress works, but I can guess it's something like this:

```
cy.get('#hubspot-messages-iframe-container > iframe')
.invoke('style', 'display', 'none! important')
.should('have.style', 'display', 'none !important')
```

That because display is not an attribute, it's a CSS property that should be inside a style attribute.

In case this doesn't work, perhaps something like this might:

```
cy.get('#hubspot-messages-iframe-container > iframe')
.invoke('attr', 'style', 'display: none! important')
.should('have.attr', 'style', 'display: none !important')
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. What works is: `cy.get('SELECTOR').invoke('attr', 'style', 'display: none !important').should('have.attr', 'style', 'display: none !important',)`

Comment: it doesn't work, cypress doesn't have `have.style` assertion under `should`

Comment: But I put `have.attr` not `have.style`

Answer (score 0):

P D's answer just worked for me. I also did not have to add !important to any of my styles, so to reiterate what he said, for example, this code worked for me to change invoked text to bold and a green background with a white foreground color:

```
cy.get($el).invoke('attr','style','font-weight: bold; color:#fff; background-color: #090;').invoke('text').then((text)=>{
   cy.wait(200);
});
```

I hope this helps somebody.

Bruce

Comment: Here is a short video showing exactly that https://testautomationu.applitools.com/advanced-cypress-tutorial/chapter4.html